# R: Issues of duplication of coefficient when running lm() with csv

Tags: r, csv, lm

So I've pulled my data from my csv using read.csv and that is working fine. 
Code:

```
 techdata <- read.csv("/user/path", header = TRUE, sep = ",", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I've check the data as an output in r and it is properly formatted and seems fine.

But when I run

```
techFit <- lm(techdata$reordered_in_next_30_days ~techdata$work_order_frequency)
summary(techFit)
```

I get this

```
Call:
lm(formula = techdata$reordered_in_next_30_days ~ techdata$work_order_frequency)

Residuals:
   Min     1Q Median     3Q    Max 
-5.416 -0.886 -0.283  0.372 94.531 

Coefficients:
                                  Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                        2.46871    0.03142  78.581  < 2e-16 ***
techdata$work_order_frequency1     2.94734    0.08425  34.985  < 2e-16 ***
techdata$work_order_frequency10   -0.80860    0.07465 -10.832  < 2e-16 ***
techdata$work_order_frequency100  -2.43363    0.36315  -6.702 2.08e-11 ***
techdata$work_order_frequency101  -2.26871    0.34024  -6.668 2.61e-11 ***
techdata$work_order_frequency102  -2.36591    0.26592  -8.897  < 2e-16 ***
techdata$work_order_frequency103  -2.21871    0.48387  -4.585 4.54e-06 ***
....
techdata$work_order_frequencyNULL -2.46871    0.05592 -44.151  < 2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 2.731 on 72500 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.141, Adjusted R-squared:  0.1378 
F-statistic: 44.07 on 270 and 72500 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

There should only be 1 "techdata$work_order_frequency" but there ends up being upwards of 100.

This is really making it hard for me to interpret what is going on with the data and would like to better understand why it is happening.

Comment: Could you dput() your data?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your column work_order_frequency is a character column. By default this will be read in as a factor if you use `read.csv`. This is the reason why the lm function splits this column into separate coefficients.

read in your data again with the option `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`.

Comment: I've tried this, and the problem still remains

Comment: check the structure of your data to check the factors and restart your r session before running everything again.

Comment: So, the structure seems good, columns are properly defined and organized. But I might be missing something in the structure that is necessary so any additional information/help would be appreciated.